# Grails sortableColumn with multiple fields

Tags: grails

Suppose I have two domain objects, Document and Author

```
Class Document {
    Author author
    String title
}

Class Author {

    String lastName
    String firstName

    String toString() {

        return lastName + ", " + firstName
    }
}
```

The view list.gsp looks something like this:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="title" title=... />
<g:sortableCOlumn property="author" title=... />

....

<td>${fieldValue(bean: documentInstance, field: "author"}></td>
<td>${fieldValue(bean: documentInstance, field: "title"}></td>
```

The displayed values in the table work as intended - the table row will show the author as (lastName, firstName) next to documentInstance.title.

However, clicking the Author column header to sort causes "documents" to be sorted by author.id .

What is the most expedient way to get sorting by author.toString() or "author.lastName, author.firstName" instead of sorting by author.id?

I'd prefer to avoid falling back to .withCriteria{} if possible - I have four different columns that need this functionality, and it seems like that would get messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just a Grails beginner so maybe my answer is not optimal, but this was the easiest way for me:

Instead of using `Document.list(params)` I used `Document.findAll()`. Is worth mentioning that in my application I do needed some kind of filter in my lists, so `findAll()` was the best approach.  Anyways, here is how I would do it:

```
Document.findAll( "from Document as d order by d." + params.sort + ' ' + params.order, params ) //supports pagination
```

And in the View:

```
<g:sortableCOlumn property="author.lastName" title=... />
```

Comment: I ended up using withCriteria ... I'm going to mark this as the answer since seems like the cleanest solution to the question "as asked". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [derived property](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) to create a virtual column to sort on:

```
Class Author {

    String lastName
    String firstName
    String sortingName

    static mapping {
        // modify the SQL formula to use your DB's concatenation operator
        sortingName formula: "`LAST_NAME` || ',' || `FIRST_NAME`)" // Standard SQL
    }

    String toString() { sortingName }
}
```

Then set your column to `sortingName`:

```
<g:sortableColumn property="author.sortingName" title=... />
```

(I'm kind of guessing here, but I think this should work.)

Comment: That sounds like it should work, but I'd rather not involve direct use of SQL if I can avoid it. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Assuming to the http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties point 7.5.2.11, after sortingName there shouldn't be a colon.

Comment: @Tadek Good catch, it appears that you are correct.  That's the issue with DSLs like this, though, sometimes it's hard to tell what's a property and what's a function call.  :-)

Comment: I catch it because I have something similar to write and in this form (which You propose) it's perfectly suitable for me! :)